# How to add Icons to SlidingTabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tabs

I made sliding tabs using this lesson:
http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html
How to use icons instead of text in Sliding tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this function in ViewPagerAdapter.java and add my icon:

```
@Override
 public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Drawable drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(icons[position]);
        drawable.setBounds(0,0,48,48);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" ");
        spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0,spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return spannableString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put imageviews into your tab layouts. For example, instead of using their Tab1.xml, you could use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/yourIconImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In this case, an icon appears on the fragment, but not the tab